# Beamer: what is purpose of .vrb files?

Tags: beamer

Recently i work on presentation prepared with Beamer. every time when i made some error in document typing `X` in editor (WinEdt,) open me file `.vrb` with frame, where i made error.

That is fine, but not much useful to me. correction done there are not transferred to my document. so i wondering, what is purpose of this file? only to more easy  find this frame in document?

**edit:**

i research again when `.vrb` file is open. its not caused with some error but when i use "back search" facility of `pdf` previewer (Sumatra in my case) and click on the shoved slide. if it contain verbatim text, than this open `.vrb` file and nod return to `.tex` file, where is code for this frame. otherwise this doesn't happen.

anyway, i'm still curious about how this file displayed in editor can be useful for someone. let me noted, that in `.verb`is only part of frame code.

Comment: Isn't this the verbatim file created when you use the fragile option?

Comment: @daleif, hm, so far didn't notice this. in open file i see the frame, which may contain  some verbatim text (which is not in error). hm, i must check this again ...

Comment: I'm quite sure this is exactly how fragile works

Comment: @daleif is totally right. You can also see that the content of a fragile frame is outsourced to the .vrb file by using synxtex: Try to jump from the pdf to the code of a fragile frame and you will end up in the .vbr file instead of the .tex file.

Comment: The `.vrb` file is created by a macro `\beamer@doexternalframe` which, in turn, is called by beamer's frame parser when the switch `\ifbeamer@isfragile` is true.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik So sad. I always thought `vrb` would stand for `very reasonable bug`, but now you've taken my illusion... ;-)

Comment: @marmot Perhaps the `\ifbeamer@isfragile` isn't referring to the contents of the frame, but to the code. Then your hypothesis might be true :)

Comment: Vaguely related (certainly no duplicate) question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340292/synctex-and-fragile-beamers-frame

Answer (score 5):

The content of the body text of `fragile` frames gets a special treatment. Instead of processing it multiple times, like normal beamer frames, it is written to a special file, the `.vrb` (I assume this is short for verbatim?) and read directly from there. This allows you to have code in the frame, which would normally not work with beamer.

Synctex will always link to the file from where the problematic code was read in. For example if there is an error within a package, it will link to the .sty file. This also means that if there is an error within the fragile frame it will link to the `.vrb` file.

In theory you could use some sed replacement to replace the name of the vrb file with the original tex file in the syntex file (similar what to what ltx2any does to deal with build folders), but this would need some magic to get the line numbers right.

Comment: thank you for explanation. it convinced me even more, that `.vrb` file rather distract me than help in preparation of slides. i case of observed error  you can't  return from slide to real file in editor using back search mechanism of `sumatra` for example.

Comment: After six year I return to beamer again ... Many frames are in `fragile` mode, and appearing `vrb`. frame in editor is unfortunately (at least to me) only disturbing in writing of presentations. Is there a way to block it to show in editor or that "magic" mentioned in your answer will be available soon?

Comment: @Zarko Whether or not your editor will open the .vrb files is completely up to your editor.