How to use beamer definitions (like author, date) for reusing text in hyperref to change PDF meta data?
Assume, I set a date that I wanna alter more often than the rest of the presentation (e,g., my long title gets reused and reused) information, and therefore wanna use the \insertdate a lot. Mostly, I want to use it for information in the PDF metadata, which I considered setting through the \hyperref package using hypersetup.
I have a problem that I describe below, see the picture:

I know, not the most minimal of a MWE, but I wanna demonstrate which packages I really need for this project. Hope that's alright.
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,12pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, isbn=false ]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\title[myshorttitle \# \insertdate \DTMsetstyle{iso} \today ~(as I want it in the footer)]{My really long title (that always stays the same)}
\subtitle[]{
\texorpdfstring{My very important subtitle \\ and a beautiful date: \DTMsetstyle{en-GB}\today}%for_document
{My V.I.S}}%for_metadata
%thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656198 for texorpdfstring
\author{\texorpdfstring{I.~Lastname\inst{1}}{PDF Info Author}
} 

\institute[Shortinst]{\inst{1}%
The number (below), set as a date, needs to appear on the title slide: \\ 
  Below you find my ``fake date'', hahaha
}
\date{99}


\hypersetup{
pdftitle = {myhorttitle~\insertdate},
pdfsubject  = {\insertsubtitle~My beloved number~\insertdate}, 
  pdfkeywords = {the only part that actually works, presentation, current year, 2024}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]{What I want with my fake date}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161241/114622 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347096/how-to-use-verb-in-the-main-title-of-a-beamer-presentation
My ``fake date'', using (\verb|\insertdate|) should give me
\begin{itemize}
    \item the number I set in my footer $\checkmark$
    \item flexibility in pdf settings in \verb|\hypersetup|, especially with other \texttt{inserts} it should alter the \verb|\hypersetup{pdftitle=...|
\end{itemize}


\end{frame}
\end{document}


I'm able to use \insertdate as part of the \hypersetup setup. It's not entirely clear where you want the \insertdate to show and where it currently doesn't show.

\texttt{} just changes the font. why do you expect it to make the text verbatim? it's like \textit{} or \textsf{}.

could you explain what you want \hypersetup to do? the commands you are using set the title, date and subject of the pdf itself. this is the information your pdf viewer shows when you look at document 'properties' or that pdfinfo <filename> displays. that is, it applies to the pdf as a whole. it makes no sense to change it halfway through as there's only one 'slot' for each of those bits of meta data.

@canIchangethis please only ask one question per post. You should edit your question to remove unrelated questions about typewriter fonts.

@canIchangethis ... it might also be a good idea to clean up your preamble. You have many unnecessary packages there that you don't need to load in a beamer presentation.

@Werner the thing is, for me it does NOT work in \pdftitle

I though \texttt{} is also a way to make something verbatim, my bad, will remove the part! @cfr But no, I do not want to change the metadata within one project, I just want to use the project above as a template for further projects where the number in \insertdate increases

Oh yea, I will totally remove that part @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. but the packages I included are all used in my personal beamerstylefile and while I don't need them with Szeged I thought I have a solution that works with them included.

@canIchangethis even if you use another theme, you don't have to load graphicx or hyperref. You also don't need inputenc if your tex distribution has been updated this decade. Only include the packages which you need.

Thank you so much! My tex distribution is overleaf, so I hope that's true :)

Hahaha @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz as soon as I remove these packages, I get the "Package biblatex Warning: Load 'inputenc' before biblatex." and "Package csquotes Warning: Load 'inputenc' before 'csquotes' on input line 27." (my \begin{document} is in line 27) but this should not be here as a comment anymore I guess.

@canIchangethis Is your tex distribution up-to-date? I don't get such a warning.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz TeXLive version 2024 in overleaf

@canIchangethis I don't get a warning https://www.overleaf.com/read/hyszcwknbnjy#1cbc07

Beamer will normally automatically generate the pdf meta data from your title, author etc.
You can use the usepdftitle=false to suppress this and do your own meta data:
\documentclass[usepdftitle=false]{beamer}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\title[myshorttitle \# \insertdate \DTMsetstyle{iso} \today ~(as I want it in the footer)]{My really long title (that always stays the same)}
\subtitle[]{
\texorpdfstring{My very important subtitle \\ and a beautiful date: \DTMsetstyle{en-GB}\today}%for_document
{My V.I.S}}%for_metadata
%thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656198 for texorpdfstring
\author{\texorpdfstring{I.~Lastname\inst{1}}{PDF Info Author}
} 

\institute[Shortinst]{\inst{1}%
The number (below), set as a date, needs to appear on the title slide: \\ 
  Below you find my ``fake date'', hahaha
}
\date{99}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle = {myhorttitle~\insertdate},
pdfsubject  = {\insertsubtitle~My beloved number~\insertdate}, 
  pdfkeywords = {the only part that actually works, presentation, current year, 2024}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thank you so much! If I had just known about "usepdftitle=false" setting, I would have saved hours of researching!

@canIchangethis Please don't forget to edit your question

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: I'm suspecting one can do the same if you use an appropriate mixture of \texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>} in the \title and friends.
